# Firefox: Network Monitor: How to debug JSON payload?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-edition

I switched from Google Chrome to Firefox Developer's Edition because of memory leak issues and moving towards truly open-source solution.

I want to debug the payload of my request which is JSON but Firefox does not show the user-friendly tree structure of JSON data. Is there any plugin? How can I improve the Network Monitor?

[image: Firefox Developer Edition > Network monitor > Params]

Answer (score 2):

It has been fixed and is now available. Just update your browser using the about Firefox.

The bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1122102

[image]

Comment: Now, it's more like Developer's Browser! +1